# how do i write assembly code from c#?

Tags: c#, .net, assembly, reflection.emit

i want to write a string of assembly code in c# and have it sent to some win32 api to compile and execute it and get the results back.

example:

```
string str = "MOV 1,2;XOR EBP,EBP"...
```

sounds like hard to do but any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: May I ask why you need this? For drivers or efficiency or other?

Comment: if it could be done, i am intending to hand-craft a simple sorting algorithm in assembly and compare it with a .net c# one

Comment: Hm ... .Net bytecode is JIT-ed for the specific architecture. I know you can get to the IL, but I wonder if you can snitch the piece of code that is compiled to machine code. Then you could look at the code, try to beat it yourself. This WILL BE hardware-specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is x86 assembler via .NET possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137544/is-x86-assembler-via-net-possible) - Also see [this project](http://code.google.com/p/managed-x86/source/browse/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is x86 assembler via .NET possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137544/is-x86-assembler-via-net-possible)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt there's a win API to compile & execute assembly.
Probably the best you could do is write a file, execute MASM (or whatever it's called these days), link it then execute the resulting program.
I can't imagine what you are trying to do but this would be pretty much the last way I would try to solve almost any problem!

If you want to compare native & managed code, just write two programs that do more or less the same thing.  There is no reason to generate the assembly from .NET.  You can use any suitable tool for this.  MASM, debug etc.

Comment: +1 but I think it's after the last way I would try to solve any problem.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no assembler compiler available as a part of WinAPI. You would have to use some of the 3rd party compilers (and your program would need to redistribute it).

However, you can use `ilasm` which is a part of .NET framework. (Beware however that it's not an Intel32 compiler, its source is [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) code, so the instructions like `xor ebp, ebp` wouldn't work.)