# Assembler Language support for ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, assembly

Does anyone know if there is a package available that supports assembler code.
I would like to do something like this:

```
<html>
<div id="useless">
<%
  mov ah,09                         ;
  mov dx,"Hello World.$"            ;
  int 21h                           ;
  mov ah,4ch                        ;
  mov al,00                         ;
  int 21h                           ;
%>
</div>
</html>
```

Just because this isn't a good idea doesn't mean I can't want it.

Comment: You can't use assembler in .Net, period.

Comment: Even if you could use x86 assembly language, your example depends on DOS.  If you're really a glutton for punishment, maybe at least look into IL so you are on the same platform.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is x86 assembler via .NET possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137544/is-x86-assembler-via-net-possible)

Comment: @BoPersson Not a duplicate, that post is asking if it is possible to do the string -> byte translation for assembly, not execute the assembly. The closest is probably this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330322/how-do-i-write-assembly-code-from-c

Answer (score 1):

You can create a DLL in C with assembler blocks, then call it from ASP.Net using P/Invoke.

There are an infinite number of better options.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could stream the assembler in a request to file, call something external to assemble, run it, get results somehow and post it back. It would need some major circumvention of ASP.NET security though.

But even if you somehow manage to do that calling 16-bit Dos INT functions won't work in a win32/64 process. So it would have to be a DOS assembler. Afaik old MASMS and TASMs are downloadable.

In Windows 64-bit you'd also need to run both (assembler and result) in a dosbox that emulates 16-bit assembler, since 16-bit  programs don't work in long mode.

**But: IT IS CRAZY!!!! !!!!**